# Dissociation of Water?

Tags: acid-base

My teacher told me that 1 in 553 million water molecules dissociate.

However, since water has a pH of 7, shouldn’t 1 in every 10,000,000 water molecules dissociate?

Comment: You have a concentration of 10e-7 mol/L for pH 7 (at the usual conditions and approximations). How many molecule of water are there in one litre?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [. . .] water has a pH of 7, shouldn’t 1 in every 10,000,000 water molecules dissociate?

To answer this question, what does pH really mean?

Taken from [Chemistry Libretexts - pH and pOH](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Chemistry_(OpenSTAX)/14%3A_Acid-Base_Equilibria/14.2%3A_pH_and_pOH), pH is defined as follows,

> The pH of a solution is therefore defined as shown here where $\ce{[H3O+]}$ is the **molar concentration of hydronium ion in the solution**:
> $$\mathrm{pH} = -\log \ce{[H3O+]} \tag{14.2.2}$$
> (emphasis mine)

This means at pH $7$, there are $\pu{10^-7 mol}$ of $\ce{H3O+}$ in $\pu{1 l}$ of water.

This means that $\pu{10^-7 mol}$ of water dissociate. But now how many moles are there in $\pu{1 l}$ of water?

There are a total of $\pu{55.49952 moles}$ in $\pu{1 l}$ of water. Therefore $1$ in every $\pu{554995200 molecules}$ of water dissociate to be exact. This is assuming $\pu{0.9998395 g/cm3}$ to be the density of water though.

Comment: pH is defined for activity a(H+), not concentration. [IUPAC Gold Book ref.](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/P04524). Libretexts used the simplification for education reasons. // Molar amount with 4 valid digits cannot lead to molecule count with 9 valid digits.

Comment: @Poutnik The textbooks are also lazy about units when they do that. It makes more sense to write $$\mathrm{pH} \approx -\log \frac{[\ce{H3O+}]}{\pu{1 M}}\tag{ for dilute solutions}$$

Comment: @Karsten Sure, as arguments of logarithms ( and most of other functions)  must be unitless, as activity is, being defined as $\mu = \mu_0 + RT\ln{(a)}$.